# access, OpenDatabase() relative path

Tags: vba, ms-access

Hello I have 2 accdb files in one folder, I need to open second file from first file and I have to use relative path. I tryed everything, but nothing works.

```
Set db = DBEngine(0).OpenDatabase(ActiveDocument.Path & "\Training.accdb") 
Set db = DBEngine(0).OpenDatabase("..\Training.accdb")
```

result: error, missing object

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Any reason why the two DB's are not linked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
Set db = DBEngine(0).OpenDatabase(CurrentProject.Path & "\Training.accdb")
```

The setting `ActiveDocument.Path`, doesn't exists in Access.